# Why is the type alias required when implementing the `std::ops::Add` trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I exercised coding in Rust using the [Rust By Practice](https://practice.rs/why-exercise.html) book. I have encountered an example where I got a little bit confused. The following code is a revised version of the 4th exercise in the **Traits** chapter:

```
use std::ops;

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct LeftHandSide;

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct RightHandSide;

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct LeftAndRightHandSide;

impl ops::Add<RightHandSide> for LeftHandSide {
    type Output = LeftAndRightHandSide;

    fn add(self, _rhs: RightHandSide) -> LeftAndRightHandSide {
        LeftAndRightHandSide
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(LeftHandSide + RightHandSide, LeftAndRightHandSide);
    println!("Success!");
}
```

It was completed by deriving the `PartialEq` and the `Debug` trait default implementation for the structures. It is mandatory because the `assert_eq!` macro compares and prints out (on panic) the values of the expressions. Additionally, the `Add` trait left-hand side and right-hand side have to be in the right order.

The adding trait requires the `type Output` alias, but it is not used anywhere. According to the [Addable points](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html#addable-points) example, the alias is also not used.

Why is the type alias required when implementing the `std::ops::Add` trait?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it is not used anywhere" it's clear as day used in the definition of the `fn add(self, other: Rhs) -> Self::Output` method.

Comment: I meant for the https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html#addable-points implementation where the `Self` is used instead of `Self::Output` as the return type.

Comment: When you write `type Output = Self` you can subsequently use `Self` and `Self::Output` interchangably, doesn't mean it's not used.

Comment: In my case, the associated type is the `type Output = LeftAndRightHandSide;`. However, when I was printing out the type in order to check the interchangeability, I got an error. I placed the `println!("{:?}, {:?}", LeftAndRightHandSide, Self::Output);` line under the `add` method.

Comment: Uhm yea, interchangably as a type, not as a value. `LeftAndRightHandSide` is a little confusingly both a type and a value of that type.

Comment: Oh, I see! That is the reason why the `Self::Output` can only be used interchangeably with the `LeftAndRightHandSide` type on the method signature. And not as the return **value** of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trait is a kind of interface. It can declare associated functions, associated types and associated constants that *any* implementer of the trait must implement, since they are part of the interface.

Let's look at an example. We have this trait:

```
trait Glonk {
    type Wobble: Default;
}
```

Now we use this trait in a generic function:

```
fn get_wobble<T: Glonk>() -> T::Wobble {
    Default::default()
}
```

You can see that we require `T` to implement `Glonk`. Since the `Wobble` type is part of the public interface of `Glonk`, we know that any implementer of `Glonk` has `T::Wobble`, so we can use it in our function. That's the point of traits. We don't know exactly what type we get, but we get the guarantee that the type we get implements everything declared in the trait. If we want to implement `Glonk` for a type, we need to define what `Wobble` is for that specific type.

Now let's look at the defintion of the `Add` trait.

```
pub trait Add<Rhs = Self> {
    type Output;
    fn add(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;
}
```

This is slightly more complex than our `Glonk` trait, but we can see that the trait declares the associated type `Output`. This means any implementer of the trait needs to include a definition of the `Output` type. It doesn't matter whether the type is used anywhere. It's part of the interface, so any consumer of the trait *might* use it. The type also *is* used as the return type of `add()`, but it doesn't really matter for the question whether you need to define it in an implementation of `Add`.

In future versions of Rust, it will eventually be possible to declare [*associated type defaults*](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2532-associated-type-defaults.html):

```
trait Glonk {
    type Wobble: Default = i32;
}
```

This will declare a default type for the assoicated type, so implementers can skip defining the type. This feature is not avaialable in stable Rust yet, and the `Add` trait won't implement a default for its `Output` type anyway, so this won't change anything about this specific example.

Comment: I see so the `type` keyword is not only used for aliasing. It can be also applied to declare an associated type. Moreover, a struct that implements a trait has to implement all of the associated types and associated functions, if no defaults are provided.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the type alias required when implementing the std::ops::Add trait?

It's not a type alias, it's an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html), which is an intrinsic part of the trait implementation: it can be referred to generically when interacting with the type. For instance

```rust
pub fn double<O, T: Add<Output=O> + Copy>(t: T) -> O
{
    t + t
}
```

> The adding trait requires the type Output alias, but it is not used anywhere. According to the Add documentation, the alias is also unused.

It is not though? The associated type is the output of `add`:

```rust
fn add(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;
```